# C# - passing SomeClass to a function instead of typeof(SomeClass)

Tags: c#, constructor, typeof

I've implemented an `ActionFilterAttribute` which maps `SomeClass` to `SomeOtherClass`. Here's the constructor:

```
public class MapToAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private Type _typeFrom;
    private Type _typeTo;
    public int Position { get; set; }

    public MapToAttribute(Type typeFrom, Type typeTo, int Position = 0)
    {
        this.Position = Position;
        this._typeFrom = typeFrom;
        this._typeTo = typeTo;
    }

    ...
}
```

The way to call this is currently:

```
MapTo(typeof(List<Customer>), typeof(List<CustomerMapper>), 999)
```

For aesthetical reasons, I'd prefer to be able to do

```
MapTo(List<Customer>, List<CustomerMapper>, 999)
```

I've tried doing

```
    public MapToAttribute(object typeFrom, object typeTo, int Position = 0)
    {
        this.Position = Position;
        this._typeFrom = typeof(typeFrom);
        this._typeTo = typeof(typeTo);
    }
```

but to no avail, since Visual Studio will pretend that `typeFrom` and `typeTo` are undefined.

---

Edit: The (otherwise obviously proper, as pointed out below) use of Generics is not supported for `Attribute`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a type as a variable. Generally, you can use generics to get rid of the `typeof`:

```
public class MapToAttribute<TFrom, TTo> : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private Type _typeFrom;
    private Type _typeTo;
    public int Position { get; set; }

    public MapToAttribute(int Position = 0)
    {
        this.Position = Position;
        this._typeFrom = typeof(TFrom);
        this._typeTo = typeof(TTo);
    }

    ...
}
```

Usage:

```
new MapToAttribute<List<Customer>, List<CustomerMapper>>(999);
```

**Problem:**
C# doesn't allow generic attributes, so you are stuck with `typeof`.
There is no other way.

Comment: Hey Daniel. Thanks for the swift answer. I'm not sure though whether I can use generics in `Filter` attributes. Gonna try now.

Comment: Update: you cannot use generics in `Attribute`s. Bummer.

Comment: @vzwick: That's a pity. I updated my answer accordingly. You are stuck with `typeof`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. A type cannot be passed as a parameter unless using generics or typeof. Daniel Hilgarth's solution is great, but won't work if your class is intended to be used as an attribute as c# doesn't allow generic attributes.